# casting array type for recursive template evaluation

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I would have loved to include a minimal example, but due to the nature of my question I can not provide one.

I reduce my problem to not being able to typecast an array. Here is a code snippet that shows what I would want to write:

```
template <size_t N>
size_t arrLen(int(&data)[N])
{
    return N;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    size_t working = arrLen(arr);

    int * p = &arr[1];
    size_t len = 3;

    size_t len_is_not_a_constant_value = arrLen(*(int(*)[len])p);
}
```

My playground algorithm is find any peak in a 1D array where peak is defined as bigger or equal to the peaks neighbors. The algorithm itself is not too important to me. The following code has commented out the lines that i would like to include but can not since it would not compile. The algorithm is incorrect without those lines.

```
template <size_t N>
int getpeak1D_templated(int(&data)[N])
{
    size_t offset = N / 2;

    if (data[offset] < data[offset - 1])
    {
        int * p = data;
        size_t len = offset;
        //return getpeak1D_templated(*(int(*)[len])p);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (data[offset] < data[offset + 1])
    {
        int * p = &data[offset];
        size_t len = N - offset;
        //return offset + getpeak1D_templated(*(int(*)[len])p);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return offset;
    }
}

int getpeak1D_templated(int(&data)[1])
{
    return 0;
}

int getpeak1D_templated(int(&data)[2])
{
    if(data[0] < data[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the not templated version. This would compile and should be correct.

```
int getpeak1D(int * data, size_t N)
{
    size_t offset = N / 2;

    size_t offset_m1 = offset - 1;
    size_t offset_p1 = offset + 1;

    if (N >= offset_m1 && data[offset] < data[offset_m1])
    {
        return getpeak1D(data, offset);
    }
    else if (N >= offset_p1 && data[offset] < data[offset_p1])
    {
        return offset + getpeak1D(data + offset, N - offset);
    }
    else
    {
        return offset;
    }
}
```

I can see why this `*(int(*)[len])p` is invalid.

It feels like there is something that I am missing. This recursion terminates and I would be able to write all specializations out by hand (for reasonable starting array sizes). I am assuming that I am doing something wrong here. Somehow this recursion should be possible using templates.

Is there an array casting version that I am missing?

Is there something completely different that I missed?

EDIT: 
I actually *can* see why this is invalid. My point is N is constant and all operations are so well defined that they could be resolved at compile time. So for an array of size N all branches of the recursion could be unrolled. I am looking for a way of getting there. The cast is incorrect and will never be correct.

Comment: The compiler will probably unroll the non-templated version if it's in the same translation unit as the caller.  If not, possibly [duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) might help.

Comment: The non templated version has an array bound check in it so if that does not get optimized away performance is lost. The templated Version has no need for that since it can just implement different specializations for the relevant cases.

Comment: If the compiler can automatically unroll the recursive calls, it should eliminate the bounds check.  It might be worth checking `-S` or `objdump -d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't you just replace len in the commented lines with N/2 and N-N/2.
Something like this:

```
template <size_t N>
int getpeak1D_templated(int(&data)[N])
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    size_t offset = N / 2;
    if (data[offset] < data[offset - 1])
    {
        int * p = data;
        ret = getpeak1D_templated(*(int(*)[N/2])p);
    }
    else if (data[offset] < data[offset + 1])
    {
        int * p = &data[offset];
        ret =  offset + getpeak1D_templated(*(int(*)[N - N/2])p);
    }
    else
    {
        ret =  offset;
    }
    return ret;
}

int getpeak1D_templated(int(&data)[1])
{
    return 0;
}

int getpeak1D_templated(int(&data)[2])
{
    if(data[0] < data[1]) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes actually you are correct. When reducing my problem to a minimum i removed the fact that N is constant from my thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

The error should be pretty clear. For one, `len` is not a compile time constant, and you cannot have a variable-length array (or cast to a pointer to it). Secondly, how is `arrLen` supposed to instantiate at compile time, without knowing what `len` is?

Go with your non-template version.

Answer (score 1):

If `len` is not a compile time constant integral expression, there is no way you can achieve this. And it would mean nothing, either.¹

You would really just need to pass an `array_view` or similar. See the CppCoreGuidelines: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Ri-array

### ¹ Evil Twisted Workaround

You could always switch on `len` and do casts:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

template <size_t N>
constexpr size_t arrLen(int(&)[N]) { return N; }

template <typename T, size_t N> using Array = T[N];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Array<int, 6> arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

    arrLen(arr);

    int * p = &arr[1];
    size_t len = argc>1? std::stoul(argv[1]) : 3ul;

    size_t result;
    switch (len) {
        case 1:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 1>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 2:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 2>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 3:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 3>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 4:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 4>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 5:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 5>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 6:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 6>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 7:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 7>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 8:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 8>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 9:  result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 9>&  >(*p)); break;
        case 10: result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 10>& >(*p)); break;
        case 11: result = arrLen(reinterpret_cast<Array<int, 11>& >(*p)); break;
        default: throw std::range_error("len");
    }

    return result;
}
```